# Is there an 'emergency plan' in the Android API?

Tags: android, exception

Is there a way to execute a method after the App crashed (a certain number times)?

**Example:** Sometimes with every run data changes in a way that the app does not crash anymore. So, this way it may recover itself after trying to start it for 2 times for example. The 3rd time would run smoothly again. Just an example!

My only idea right now would be to wrap everything inside the `onCreate` method in my main Activity in a generic try-catch block (catching `Exception`) handler. I don't think this is smart for several reasons, for example performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To catch every uncaught exception you can use following snippet:

```
public class App extends Application {

    public void onCreate() {
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
                Log.e("TAG","Implement your recovery strategy here, e.g. clean database or cache: " + e.toString());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Please note, that this is very 'hacky' solution, and if your app is in corrupted state very often there is probably something wrong with your code.